# How to access External Data using field's custom formula

Tags: visio

In order to reference a page's shapedata sheet, I use the `=ThePage!Prop.[name]` custom formula. What would be the equivalent to access external data?

Comment: Hi, Terry ! What you mean as external data ?

Comment: External Data refers to a Visio External Data source (i.e. an excel spreadsheet). I know how to create an External Data source link, but don't know how to access the data in a Field >> Custom formula. I would use `=ThePage!Prop.[name]` to access a page's shapedata sheet info. I'm looking for the equivalent for the External Data.

Answer (score 1):

When you drop row from **External Data Window** to your shape Visio application engine automatically create from this shape group and add into this group few shapes (text callouts)[image]
Also Visio add to this text callouts user-defined cells and fill these cells data from row of **External Data Window**.

Comment: That's really useful, thank you. However, what I'm trying to access is External Data from Fields' custom fomulas. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible with standard MS Visio Tools. May be [Visio BackSync add-in](http://unmanagedvisio.com/products/visio-back-sync/) by user [Nikolay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929187/nikolay) can help